# improving the efficiency of for loops for multi-dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have this MATLAB code as part of my project, as per the information I got from the professor's report, most of the time is spent in the `while` loop. Any suggestions regarding how can
I improve the efficiency? Generally, how can I make the for loops more efficient?

```
% p is 2D matrix of big size
s=size(p); 
pp=p;
p=zeros(s(1),s(2));

 while(norm(p-pp)>0.05 )
       p=pp;
       for n=1:N 
                  z=0;
                  for miu=1:C
                       z = z + p(n,miu) * funQ(n,miu,p,R,N,C); % call function funQ
                  end  

         for lambda=1:C                            
                  pp(n,lambda) = (p(n,lambda) * funQ(n,lambda,p,R,N,C))/z; % call function funQ
          end 
       end   
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `funQ` does but if it is amenable to vectorization then, you can try the following:

Replace

```
for miu=1:C
z = z + p(n,miu) * funQ(n,miu,p,R,N,C); % call function funQ
end
```

With

```
miu=1:C
z = sum(p(n,miu) * funQ(n,miu,p,R,N,C)); % call function funQ
```

---

Similarly,

Replace

```
for lambda=1:C                            
pp(n,lambda) = (p(n,lambda) * funQ(n,lambda,p,R,N,C))/z; % call function funQ
end
```

With

```
pp(n,:) = (p(n,lambda) * funQ(n,lambda,p,R,N,C))/z; % call function funQ
```